# What are some approaches to exchange data without using SSL/TLS

Tags: security, ssl, web, https, cdn

When creating any kind of application web,api etc; This days the best practices recommend to secure endpoints by using TLS, but what we can learn from the [cloudbleed](https://blog.cloudflare.com/incident-report-on-memory-leak-caused-by-cloudflare-parser-bug/) issue, is that it may not be enough.

Therefore I would like to know what could be done to keep a certain level of security even when TLS is compromised.

For web applications what I currently use is [jsencrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt), basically encrypts all data on client browser side before it is sent, but in order to to this I need first to exchange a shared secret (token/cookie) between the server and client, but when dealing with API's that don't support javascript what could be used?

Regarding the exchange of tokens, by instinct it may be obvious to say use OAUTH, [OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/),  [json tokens](https://jwt.io/) , but all of them require or delegate trust to TLS, and again when this is compromised it became useless.

If I am right OpenID could be used without SSL to share a "common secret" by doing  [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), is there something similar that could be implemented keeping in mind that if TLS gets compromised, easy measure could be taking like revoking tokens or changing "[salts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))" ?

For now I think by following the gpg or rsa (private/public) keys is the way to go, in a way that probably everyone could have access to the public keys but will not be available to see the content of some data signed to a specific user.

But question remains in how to exchange that very first "known secret" between client and server avoiding a possible [man in the middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) considering TLS can't be trusted.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of exchanging the first "known secret" is the same for all protocols, SSL or not. SSL is a public key infrastructure where the basic information that needs to be distributed is the public key of the root certificate of the certificate issuer. The public keys for all ssl certificate issuers are distributed with the browser installation.

Any protocol will depend on some information that is communicated between the server and client in a different channel from the channel where the communication is established. If you don't trust the SSL infrastructure, you will have to send this information by email, postal mail, sms, or by some other means.

However, your problem does not start with the keys neccesary for the encryption libraries you are using in you web application. Your very web application (the javascript files) are also sent from the server to the web browser over SSL. If your SSL communication is compromised by a man-in-the-middle, this man-in-the-middle is also probably able to change the web pages and javascript code that you send to the browser. He could just rewrite your application and remove all encryption code, add new fields and messages for the user, send the user to a different site and so on.

The SSL infrastructure is really a cornerstone in web security, and a neccessity for web applications. Without it, you would have to build a custom protocol for sending encrypted web pages and write a custom browser that would understand this protocol.

With all that said, it is of course possible to add a tiny layer of extra security on top of SSL. You may i.e. create a private/public keypair for each user, send a public key to the user and encrypt all messages from your server to the user with the private key. This could protect against a scenario where a main-in-the-middle is able to listen to the communication but not able to change your messages.